# If $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)$, then $A=B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove, disprove, or give a counterexample:
>
> If $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)$, then $A=B$.

Assume $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)$. Since we know $A \subseteq A$, we know $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Since $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)$, we know that $A \in \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Therefore, $A \subseteq B$ and $A=B$.

Is this proof okay?

Edit: I should note this isn't probability, $\mathcal{P}$ is the power set.

Comment: It's missing the $B \subseteq A$ bit, but the idea is right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can prove: $$\bigcup \mathcal{P}(A)=A$$$$\bigcup\mathcal{P}(B)=B$$ and by hypothesis you have $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)$ therefore $$B=\bigcup\mathcal{P}(B)=\bigcup\mathcal{P}(A)=A$$

Answer (score 11):

Everything in your answer is correct until the implication "Therefore $A \subseteq B$ and $A=B$". The second implication (i.e. that $A=B$ is not yet justified). So keep only the first, i.e. that $$A \subseteq B \tag 1$$ Reason in exactly the same way to deduce that $$B \subseteq A \tag2$$ Now combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields the result $$A=B$$

Answer (score 8):

The proof is almost okay. You need to argue why $B\subseteq A$. But it follows from the same argument.

Comment: I should use the same logic that showed A$\subseteq$B to show B$\subseteq$A? And thus, A=B?

Comment: @CharlesNosbig Just say something like, "By symmetry, $B \subseteq A$ as well."

Comment: @Charles: Yes, you should.

Answer (score 1):

$A\in \mathcal P (A)\rightarrow A \in \mathcal P (B)\rightarrow A\subset B$

$B\in \mathcal P (B)\rightarrow B \in \mathcal P(A)\rightarrow B\subset A$

Using the conclusions of each line $A=B$

Answer (score -1):

If we know $A$ we can determine unequivocally $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and if we know $\mathcal{P}(A)$ we can determine unequivocally A, as element of  $\mathcal{P}(A)$ which includes any subset , so if $A=B$ then $\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B)$ and if $A\neq B$ then $\mathcal{P}(A)\neq\mathcal{P}(B)$ what completes the proof of your theorem.

Another way of proving:
$$(\mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(B))\implies [(A\in\mathcal{P}(B)) \wedge (B\in\mathcal{P}(A))]\implies [(A \subseteq B) \wedge (B \subseteq A)]\\
[(A \subseteq B) \wedge (B \subseteq A)] \implies [(A\cup B=B) \wedge (B\cup A=A)]\implies (A=B)$$

PS. -1 as rating of my answer is more against reputation of math.stackexchange.com , than mine.

Comment: This construction only works for finite sets.  We should take the element that is maximal under inclusion.

Comment: *Injection*, not *bijection*.

Comment: ... and exactly the assertation that $A\mapsto P(A)$ (not $P(A)$ which is a set, not a function) is an injection is what needs to be proved here.

Comment: Or take the union of all elements _i.e_ sets in $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: @egreg it can be also bijection.

Comment: @JohannesHahn it was proved when you were reading my answer.

Comment: @egreg injective function, be accurate, if you require it from me.

Comment: @UriBrezner if set of the sets is not the power set , it doesn't work.

Comment: @Darius *You* were using the term “bijection”.

Comment: @egreg injective function may be also bijection

Comment: There is no reason for hating correct answer. It's against reputation of math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohannesHahn You have written: "...... (not *P*$(A)$ which is a set, not a function)...", if understand you $\sin(x)$ is a number , not a function?

Comment: @Darius: Exactly. sin is the function, sin(x) is the value of that function at the point x.

Comment: @JohannesHahn but there is a custom using term , function $sin(x)$ , and there is no rational reason for persecuting such a people, or using sanction against them, because it can lead to defeat and scarcity , isn't it Johann?

Comment: Whoa calm down there. Nobody said anything about persecuting or sanctioning.